# numerical inversion of multidimensional Laplace transform implementation

Tags: numerical-methods

There are many implementations available of algorithms that numerically invert the Laplace transform in one dimension (e.g. Talbot or Euler algorithms) in languages such as Mathematica, Matlab and Python.

I am looking for an implementation (in any language) in case of multiple dimensions, or something that I could code up myself. Please let me know if you are aware of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperantly it is not so hard. You can just take e.g. the Talbot algorithm, and then write a double for-loop, where each for loop inverts one dimension.